# How can I compare items in a jagged array?

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I would like to create a jagged array of a certain type, and then create another array from that based on comparisons between two items in the array.

For example:

```
int[][] arr = new int[][] 
{
    new int[] {1,3,5,7,9},
    new int[] {0,2,4,6},
    new int[] {11,22},
    new int[] {0,2,4,6}
};

int[][] arrResult = new int[arr.GetUpperBound(0)][]; 

for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
    {
        arrResult[i][j] = arr[i][j] + arr[i + 1][j];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to say that if i+1 doesn't exist, then skip that comparison.  Or is there a better way to do this?

EDIT

By compare I mean I want to access two items from the array that come after each other in column, do something with them and create an entry into a new array (with the same structure) from the product.

Comment: `based on comparisons between two items` Which items?

Comment: in the example I'm just adding arr[i][j] and arr[i+1][j] together to create arrResult[i][j], but I want to find a technique that would let me compare more complex items in the array and then produce a new array from the comparison.

Comment: 1) You do not *compare* anything. 2) What is the rule to pick up two items to *add*

Comment: Sorry, by compare I mean I want to access two items from the array that come after each other in column, do something with them and create an entry into a new array (with the same structure) from the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing but adding. So it is not clear what you really want to do.

If you want to perform an operation on corresponding items in two consecutive rows, you can do so only for the minimum length of the two rows

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length && j < arr[i + 1].Length; j++) {
        arrResult[i][j] = arr[i][j] + arr[i + 1][j];
    } 
}
```

Comment: I replaced the `GetUpperBound()` by `Length - 1` as suggested by svick.

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need `GetUpperBound()` here. That's useful for multidimensional arrays (or non-0-based arrays), not jagged arrays. Instead, you can use `Length - 1`.

Second, you need to create the arrays you're assigning to. `new int[count][]` doesn't create the nested arrays, so your code would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Third, you want to limit the index (and the size of the created array) by the smaller of the two sizes. You can use `Math.Min()` for that.

Put together:

```
int[][] arrResult = new int[arr.Length - 1][]; 

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
{
    int length = Math.Min(arr[i].Length, arr[i+1].Length);
    arrResult[i] = new int[length];

    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        arrResult[i][j] = arr[i][j] + arr[i + 1][j];
    }
}
```

Fourth, as an alternative, you could use LINQ [`Zip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698) (it will take care of limiting the size of the result by the shorter array):

```
int[][] arrResult = new int[arr.Length - 1][]; 

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
{
    arrResult[i] = arr[i].Zip(arr[i+1], (a, b) => a + b).ToArray();
}
```